# backspace navigating back in mvc page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

when i click on  a dropdownlist in a mvc page and then press the Backspace Key on the Keyboard the page is navigating back. how to prevent the page to navigate?

```
function prevent() {

        $(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
            var doPrevent = false;
            if (event.keyCode === 8) {
                var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
                if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' &&
                     (
                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' ||
                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'EMAIL' ||
                         d.type.toUpperCase() === 'DATE')
                     ) ||
                     d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
                    doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
                }
                else {
                    doPrevent = true;
                }
            }

            if (doPrevent) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking backspace in all modern browsers is a shortcut for "go back". You cannot override this.
You wouldn't be happy if web-pages could prevent default behavior for `Backspace`, `Ctrl+W`, `Alt+F4`.

You may want to use **event delegation** instead of checking for `event.target`:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8 && 
        ['TEXT', 'EMAIL', 'DATE'].indexOf(this.type.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Some important notes:

- `bind` is a deprecated method. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- if a document is focused, but not an input, then navigating back will occur anyway, and there is no way to prevent it
- there is actually no need to implement such behavior for readonly and disabled inputs. All modern browsers **disallow** editing readonly or disabled input itself